# Insert JavaScript in a blog post or a new page?

Tags: posts, javascript

I want to insert some JavaScript into my post. Actually those are some small apps made in JavaScript. Please let me know how to insert the JavaScript into the post ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

**EDIT** : Here are two plugins that may accomplish what you need

- [HTML Javascript Adder](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-javascript-adder/)
- [JinX - The Javascript Includer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jinx-the-javascript-includer/)

Comment: Sorry :) I dont want to hack the system!! :) is there another way?

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with two plugin solutions.